# Multiple NuGet packages overwrite DLL dependencies in build output due to different versions

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I was writing a .NET 6 application in Windows using two NuGet packages that both depend on SomeDll.dll and ran into some issues with versioning that cause my application to fail. One NuGet package depends on version 1.0.0.0 while the other depends on version 2.0.0.0. From what I can gather, between these two versions, a method was removed that breaks the functionality of the NuGet package relying on version 1.0.0.0. During my build output, it seems like version 2.0.0.0 is the dll that gets saved to the output, meaning that using the NuGet package that relies on the old function breaks when trying to use the assembly.

I've tried a few different approaches:

MyProject.csproj has the following lines added in an attempt to get the correct dll file in place for the build output without overwriting the other one:

```
<None Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)\CsvHelper\1.0.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\SomeDLL.dll">
   <Link>DLLFolder\SomeDLL.dll</Link>
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

This seems to save the file in a subdirectory within the build directory called DLLFolder with the correct versioning (1.0.0.0) while maintaining version 2.0.0.0 in the build directory.

However, loading the dll and redirecting it is where I am having issues. The first approach I took involved loading the assembly directly in MyProject.cs:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), @"DLLFolder\SomeDLL.dll");

// Use NuGet that references version 1.0.0.0
```

My debugger shows version 1.0.0.0 is loaded after this statement, but it still fails to use the NuGet properly. Adding more debugging after the NuGet is used shows that when the NuGet attempted to use SomeDLL.dll, it used the version in the build folder that the executable was in (version 2.0.0.0), loading both DLLs into the AppDomain and prioritizing the higher version.

My next approach was to try using a configuration file via app.config (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-app-config-file?view=vs-2022) and bindingRedirects to see if I could even get the NuGet using the old version to run:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="SomeDLL.dll" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />  
</dependentAssembly>
```

That didn't work either and the executable still used the newer version when using the NuGet.

My latest approach also involved using app.config, but I also ran into issues there with the newer dll taking priority. I tried following the approach taken here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/681802/two-sub-library-projects-in-one-solution-use-same

```
<runtime>  
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
      <dependentAssembly>  
        <assemblyIdentity name="SomeDLL" publicKeyToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" culture="neutral" />  
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"  
                  href="DLLFolder\SomeDLL.dll"/>  
      </dependentAssembly>  
    </assemblyBinding>  
  </runtime>
```

This also failed for me. The only other option I can think of right now is using the AssemblyLoad method and that does not seem very secure and in general, does not seem like a great idea. Is there some way where I can preserve SomeDLL version 2.0.0.0 in my build output folder while using SomeDLL version 1.0.0.0 from a subfolder? Or is this not possible?